# API [sqladmin.googleapis.com] not enabled on project [1234].

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

When running: `gcloud sql instances create example --tier=db-n1-standard-1 --region=europe-west1`
I get the error in the title, though I'm not too sure why as I do have the 'Google Cloud SQL API' enabled.

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it takes a while (a few minutes) a for the change to propagate...